# Property initialization and 'this'

Tags: c#, oop, properties, lazy-initialization

I was wandering if I could initialize a (reference type) property (when its value is `null`) using a reference to `this` keyword, but **without** using the constructor.
In some cases I do not want to use the constructor to initialize the property so, if no one accesses it, its value will not be created.
Furthermore, I don't like to separate the property declaration from it's initialization in the constructor, if possible.

A typical example is a Command declaration for MVVM pattern programming:

```
private Command FAddRecordCommand = null;
public Command AddRecordCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (this.FAddRecordCommand == null)
        {
            this.FAddRecordCommand = new Command(this.AddRecordCommandExecute);
        }
        return this.FAddRecordCommand;
    }
}

private async void AddRecordCommandExecute()
{
    //do something
}
```

I don't like to write three times the name of the `FAddRecordCommand` member...

I tried with Auto-implemented properties, but the `this` keyword is not accessible in the initialization:

```
public Command AddRecordCommand { get; } = new Command(this.AddRecordCommandExecute);
```

The compiler throws the error: **Keyword 'this' is not available in current context**

Is there a way to use the one-line declaration like the Auto-Implemented property provides, but making access to `this`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to reduce the lines of code, and the access to the private member, with this technique:

```
private Command FAddRecordCommand = null;
public Command AddRecordCommand => LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref this.FAddRecordCommand, () => new Command(this.AddRecordCommandExecute));

private async void AddRecordCommandExecute()
{
    //do something
}
```

Here I used:

- a lambda expression `=>` to replace the `get` function of the property
- the `ref` keyword to pass a reference to the `FAddRecordCommand` member to allow its value to be changed
- a lambda function `() => new ???` to return the new value needed for initialization
- the [LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazyinitializer.ensureinitialized?view=net-6.0) method to assign the initialization value (thanks to [Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko) for the suggestion)

This way the `this` keyword is available, the declaration requires only one line of code, and I access the private member only once.

passing the member as `ref` allows its value to be changed, and the `Func<TProp>` allows the new value to be created only when initial value is `null`.

If you don't like lambda expressions for property declaration, you can still declare it in one line:

```
public Command AddRecordCommand { get { return LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref this.FAddRecordCommand, () => new Command(this.AddRecordCommandExecute)); } }
```

Comment: You re-invented [Lazy<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1)

Comment: I think you've just reinvented [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-6.0), only in a thread-unsafe way...

Comment: @KlausGütter and Mattew Watson: you are both right, but Lazy<T> is not going to fit my needs.. LazyInitializer instead, as suggested by Dmitry, is the solution. Thanks anyway for yor suggestions

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the [null-coalescing assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

```
private Command addRecordCommand = null;
public Command AddRecordCommand
    => addRecordCommand ??= new Command(AddRecordCommandExecute);
```

This assigns to `addRecordCommand` only if it is null, then returns the value of that field.

Comment: I didn't know of null-coalescing assignment operator, but, anyway, it is available only for C# 8.0 and later, I am using C# 7.3. Anyway it's good to know, thanks!

Comment: For C#<8 there's always the slightly more verbose version: `addRecordCommand = addRecordCommand ?? new Command(AddRecordCommandExecute);`

Comment: but this way it continues to assign the same value to addRecordCommand member every time I access the property, isn't it? I am not saying it creates a new value, but assigns itself the same value after the first initialization

Comment: No, it will be assigned only once. See [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YXV21a).

Comment: I changed the fiddler example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WZamkS you can see that the private member continues to be assigned every time the public property value is read

Comment: @Formentz It isn't created every time. Look at this example - when you run it, note that the "ClassWithConstructor has been created" message is displayed only once, even though the property is accessed 3 times: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PvGtEf

Comment: @Mattew Watson: with the null coalescing assignment operator it is all right, it works as expected. I was arguing that the second trick proposed by Jonathan in the comments is going to assign the same reference of the same object instance to the private member every time you read the property. I mean this: `addRecordCommand = addRecordCommand ?? new Command(AddRecordCommandExecute);`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your are looking for *lazy initialization*
which you can implement with a help of [LazyInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazyinitializer?view=net-6.0)

```
// Eager command creation
private Command AddRecordCommandExecute() {
  //TODO: put the right creation and initialization code here
  return new Command(this.AddRecordCommandExecute);
}

// Backing Field
private Command FAddRecordCommand;

// Lazy initialized property:
// AddRecordCommandExecute() will be run once 
// on the first AddRecordCommand read   
public Command AddRecordCommand => LazyInitializer
  .EnsureInitialized(ref FAddRecordCommand, AddRecordCommandExecute);
```

Comment: Note that unlike [the null-coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619593/is-the-null-coalesce-operator-thread-safe), `Lazy<T>` is thread safe. So for general purpose use, it's safer to use `Lazy<T>` as per this answer rather than `??=` - especially if the object being newed is expensive or has side-effects.

Comment: seems that LazyInitializer does just like what I did with my extension method, so I can update my answer.. but is it still thread safe or not?

Comment: @Formentz: quotation from the manual:
 "The methods of `LazyInitializer` are **thread-safe** and may be called from multiple threads concurrently." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazyinitializer?view=net-6.0#thread-safety

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko great! I am going to update my answer with your suggestion and replace my extension method with LazyInitializer! thank you man!